# Conversion of QCD cross section formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, scattering-cross-section

I'm writing a program to calculate NLO cross sections for semi-inclusive high-$p_T$ pion production in proton-proton-collisions for my bachelor thesis.

I've got a paper describing the production cross section as function of the differential cross sections of the partons $\frac{d\sigma}{dv}$ and $\frac{d\sigma}{dv dw}$ where $v = 1+\frac t s$ and $w = - \frac{u}{s+t}$, with $s$,$t$,$u$ being the conventional mandelstam variables.

And I found a paper tabulating all the partonic cross sections. But unfortunately they use the formula
$$d\sigma = \frac{1}{32 \pi^2 s} \frac{d^{n-1}p_3}{p_3^0} \frac{d^{n-1}p_4}{p_4^0} \sum M_{fi} \delta \left(p_1+p_2-p_3-p_4\right)$$

How do I calculate the conversion from $\frac{d\sigma}{d^{n-1}p_3 d^{n-1}p_4}$ to $\frac{d\sigma}{dv}$? I know in principle how to deal with differentials, and that the conversion should somehow begin with $\frac{d\sigma}{dv} \frac{dv}{d^{n-1}p_3 d^{n-1}p_4}$ but I don't have a good ansatz how to deal with the posterior part...